# JNI_CreateJavaVM exit code -1?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have a problem when create JVM at JNI_CreateJavaVM method, application just 
"The program '[4616] VnptTokenCplusplus.exe: Native' has exited with code 1 (0x1).", can anybody explain this for me?

```
#include <jni.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"jvm");

JNIEnv* Vnpt_JavaCreateVM();
void Vnpt_JavaInvokeClass(JNIEnv* env);

int main(){
    JNIEnv* env = 0;
    env = Vnpt_JavaCreateVM();
    Vnpt_JavaInvokeClass(env);

    getchar();
}
JNIEnv* Vnpt_JavaCreateVM() {
    jint res;   
    JavaVM* jvm;
    JNIEnv* env;
    JavaVMInitArgs args;
    JavaVMOption options[1];

    args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_2; //  JNI_VERSION_1_2 is interchangeable for this example
    args.nOptions = 1;
    options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=.";
    args.options = options;
    args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_FALSE;
    res = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void **)&env, &args);
    if(res < 0)
    {
    }
    return env;
}
void Vnpt_JavaInvokeClass(JNIEnv* env) {
    jclass mainClass;
    jmethodID mainMethod;

    mainClass = env->FindClass( "com/vnpt/TestJDialog");
    mainMethod = env->GetMethodID(mainClass, "tokenNotify", "()V");
    env->CallVoidMethod(mainClass, mainMethod);
}
```

And output:

```
'VnptTokenCplusplus.exe': Loaded 'D:\Documents and Settings\tandaica0612\Desktop\VDC\BaoCao\Source\VnptToken\VnptTokenCplusplus\DebugX86\VnptTokenCplusplus.exe', Symbols loaded.
'VnptTokenCplusplus.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VnptTokenCplusplus.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VnptTokenCplusplus.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VnptTokenCplusplus.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\crypt32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VnptTokenCplusplus.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VnptTokenCplusplus.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msasn1.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VnptTokenCplusplus.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VnptTokenCplusplus.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VnptTokenCplusplus.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VnptTokenCplusplus.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VnptTokenCplusplus.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VnptTokenCplusplus.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VnptTokenCplusplus.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\lpk.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VnptTokenCplusplus.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\usp10.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VnptTokenCplusplus.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VnptTokenCplusplus.exe': Loaded 'D:\Documents and Settings\tandaica0612\Desktop\VDC\BaoCao\Source\VnptToken\VnptTokenCplusplus\DebugX86\jvm.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VnptTokenCplusplus.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmm.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VnptTokenCplusplus.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcr71.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VnptTokenCplusplus.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'VnptTokenCplusplus.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msctf.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
The program '[4616] VnptTokenCplusplus.exe: Native' has exited with code 1 (0x1).
```

Comment: I suggest you put something useful in the `if(res < 0)` block before you proceed any further. Ignoring failure cases is never a good idea: as here, it just gives you something harder to debug.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and did two things to solve it:

1- Add the place where jvm.dll lies (should be in the program files\java\jsdk_***\bin\server) to the PATH environment variable on your windows machine

2- Try to change the "-Djava.class.path=." to point to an actual directory or a .jar file (worked for me)