# JNI_CreateJavaVM fails in 64bit C

Tags: java, c, linker, java-native-interface, libraries

I am having a similar issue to [JNI_CreateJavaVM exit code -1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989502/jni-createjavavm-exit-code-1), except that my code runs when compiled in 32-bit, but fails when compiled in 64-bit.  I am changing my JDK location for each configuration in Visual Studio Express 2010, using the Windows SDK 7.1 platform.  My includes are:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\include; (for jni.h)
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\include\win32; (for jni_md.h)
```

and my additional libraries are:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\lib; (for jvm.lib and jawt.lib)
```

My source code is just simply trying to initialize the JVM in C and then looping infinitely to make sure that the command prompt stays open in VSC++.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "jni.h"

JNIEnv* create_vm(JavaVM ** jvm);

int i;
JavaVM* jvm;
JNIEnv * env;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    printf("Hello World!");
    env = create_vm(&jvm);

    if (env == 0) { return 7; }

    i = 0;

    while (1) { i++; }

    return 0;
}

JNIEnv* create_vm(JavaVM ** jvm) {

    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    int ret;
    JavaVMOption options;

    //Path to the java source code
    options.optionString = "-Djava.class.path=H:\\jarpath\\jarfile.jar";
    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6; //JDK version. This indicates version 1.6
    vm_args.nOptions = 1;
    vm_args.options = &options;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = 0;

    ret = JNI_CreateJavaVM(jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);

    if(ret < 0)
        printf("\nUnable to Launch JVM\n");
    return env;
}
```

Again, this works with a 32-bit configuration, where the only difference is that the JDK root directory is a 32-bit folder (i.e. Program Files(x86)).

After printing,

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Unable to load native library: Can't find dependent libraries
```

The code exits with the following error in the VSC++ console window:

```
The program '[5684] JNI_Test.exe: Native' has exited with code 1 (0x1).
```

Is there anything I'm missing in terms of libraries or basic C coding?  I haven't coded in C in a while and I'm not very familiar with the whole library linking in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code (it does not use the export .lib files and it only needs the JNI headers and JVM.dll). I've used the command

```
gcc -m64 -o test.exe small_test.cpp -I "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\include" -I "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\include\win32" -lstdc++
```

to compile it (MinGW, but VC++ should work also. Mingw uses older MSVCRT)

Check for GetLastError(). I suspect there's something wrong with the 64-bit C Run-Time.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PATH_SEPARATOR ';' /* define it to be ':' on Solaris */
#define USER_CLASSPATH "." /* where Prog.class is */

typedef /*_JNI_IMPORT_OR_EXPORT_*/ jint (JNICALL *JNI_CreateJavaVM_func)(JavaVM **pvm, void **penv, void *args);

JNI_CreateJavaVM_func JNI_CreateJavaVM_ptr;

JNIEnv* create_vm(JavaVM ** jvm)
{
    JNIEnv *env;
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    JavaVMOption options;
    HMODULE jvm_dll;
    int ret;

    options.optionString = "-Djava.class.path=D:\\monotest\\src_CJNIJava\\bin"; //Path to the java source code
    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6; //JDK version. This indicates version 1.6
    vm_args.nOptions = 1;
    vm_args.options = &options;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = 0;

    jvm_dll = LoadLibrary("C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre6\\bin\\server\\jvm.dll");

    /// You might check the GetLastError() here after the LoadLibrary()
    if(jvm_dll == NULL) { printf("can't load dll\n"); exit(1); }

    JNI_CreateJavaVM_ptr = (JNI_CreateJavaVM_func)GetProcAddress(jvm_dll, "JNI_CreateJavaVM");

    /// You might check the GetLastError() here
    if(JNI_CreateJavaVM_ptr == NULL) { printf("can't load function\n"); exit(1); }

    ret = JNI_CreateJavaVM_ptr(jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
    if(ret < 0) { printf("\nUnable to Launch JVM\n"); }
    return env;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    JNIEnv *env;
    JavaVM * jvm;
    env = create_vm(&jvm);

    if (env == NULL) { return 1; }

    int n = jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.  Now, I'm getting some other errors related to the 'HMODULE' typedef. Specifically, `JNI_Test.c(24): error C2275: 'HMODULE' : illegal use of this type as an expression.` Any pointers?

Comment: HANDLE is ok instead of HMODULE

Comment: Oooh... Sorry, this is C. Just move the "HMODULE jvm_dll" a little higher to the beginning of the create_vm(). Same with "int ret".

Comment: You may also rename the "JNI_Test.c" to "JNI_Test.cpp". Originally I mention the ".cpp" extension. C89 is "weaker" in terms of variable definitions.

Comment: EDIT :: Just saw your updates.  Yeah, worked great!  Thanks so much! :: END EDIT
I actually had to change a couple lines because I'm in pure C and not C++ (declaring `HMODULE jvm_dll` and `int ret` outside the function).  But the JVM starts with no problem.  I do get an error about `jvm` not being a struct or a union for the `DestroyJavaVM` method, but that's probably not related to my previous problem.  Thanks again!

Comment: OK. Glad to help. The JVM issue bothered me a lot and the most tricky thing was the simultaneous x86/x64 compatibility. I usually resolve such stuff by manually loading the .dlls.

Comment: There's a slight difference between C and C++ versions of the JNI. The C++ env struct is a "true" C++ class-like struct and for the C DestroyJavaVM expects an additional first parameter (a.k.a. 'this').